# CSS how to define the distance of a div from the bottom of a page, not the bottom of the window?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a page that does not fit inside the browser window so the user has to scroll to the bottom. 
I want to make a div that is 50vh from the bottom, but if I do this:

```
    .test{ 
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 50vh;
    }
```

Then it just makes it so that when the page loads it is 50vh from the bottom of the window, not 50vh from the bottom of the entire page, which extends past the window. How would I make a div that is 50vh from the bottom of the entire page?
Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want a 50vh "gap from the bottom of the div to the bottom of the rendered page"? If so, margin-bottom: 50vh; and remove the position attribute.

Comment: `vh` is the _View Height_ not an _Element's_ height. You need to use innerHeight instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `body` to have position relative. As long as the `test` element is a direct child it should work.

Here's the code to test:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.pusher {
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}

.test {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>

<div class="pusher">
  
</div>
```

And here's a link to the fiddle to play with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/v0kt9hnj/4/

Comment: This worked, thanks. I just made the position of the thing that was holding my div relative.